# Graph REST API authentication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to use the Graph REST API to create users and assign licenses for our Office 365 subscription.   I've used Graph Explorer and the API docs to find exactly what I need.   I can't seem to find good docs on how to authenticate prior to sending my get and post requests.

Can anyone point me toward docs which shows what is needed for authentication prior to sending API requests?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to authenticate with Azure AD and get a token with a proper scope to get access to data from the Microsoft Graph API.You can start from this documentation which explains how you can [authenticate and Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts).

As you are saying you are using the Graph Explorer, it is an application in Azure AD Enterprise apps which helps you make graph calls after you authenticate and authorize to some or the other scopes.

You can create a user by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to which endpoint you should hit.

You can assign licenses by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

There are some authentication flows you can use according to your requirement. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) for more details.

Comment: Thank you!   The Authenticate and Authorize link was very helpful.   The links for the create user/assign licenses were the pages I had already read when I was using Graph Explorer.   I'll give this a try in my code and will report back.   Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've having some difficulty with the information presented in the "authenticate and authorize" documentation above.   I've created an application in Azure and have assigned it the api permissions I need.   The docs seem to indicate I need to post information to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token.   The data which needs to be posted seems to be a little confusing.

Comment: I'm posting client_id=(my application/client ID from my Azure application)&scope=User.Read.All%20User.ReadWrite.All%20Directory.Read.All%20Directory.ReadWrite.All&code=(not sure - I've tried application/client ID and directory/tenant ID here)&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient   &client_secret=(the value for a secret I've created in my app under "certificates and secrets")&grant_type=authorization_code   Each time I post the data I've mentioned I receive a 400 return code.   Is the data I'm posting incorrect?   I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I understood that you are using the authorization code flow and you cannot hit the token endpoint directly to get a token, you need to get the code value from the authorize endpoint which gives in the redirect url as a parameter and then you should use the above endpoint to after putting the code value. Please go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.   I'm making a lot of progress.   I've found the flow I've selected is probably not best for my application.   The is a backend app which will run without user interaction, so authorization flow may not be best.   I've changed to using the Client Credentials flow and am making progress.   The docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow indicate I need to GET adminconsent to approve the app and then use /oauth2/v2.0/token to obtain an access token.

Comment: I've accessed /adminconsent manually and approved the access.   From my code I'm calling /oauth2/v2.0/token and am successfully obtaining an access token.   Is the hit to /adminconsent a one time operation?   It's not clear if this is a URL which needs to be used continually.   Within Graph Explorer I'm looking up a user using a call like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@example.com.   Is this the same URL I should be using within my code?   I'm calling this using (using GET) and am setting the Authorization header to the bearer token, but I receive a 401 (unauthorized) return.

Comment: If you are using the Client Crediential flow then you should specify the permissions in the portal and scope you can give as https://graph.microsoft.com/.default which will pull all the scopes which you mentioned in the portal. For me info you can go through this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph)

Comment: Thank you!   I had the scope incorrect.   My code is now working!

Comment: @BobD Glad to here that. Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions :)-